# Is there any downside to changing the email address of the APIOnly user?

Tags: api, user-management, passwords

I'd like to change the email address on the APIOnly user I set up from a specific person to the org's generic 'info@' address. Will this harm any of my integrations (primarily Form Assembly) in any way? The password is set to never expire. Thanks!

Comment: Is that address set up so someone can monitor it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes! Thanks for asking. I've changed the email address and heard back on #askforce that it should be fine as long as the owner of the info@ email address goes in and verifies the change, which they should do today.